# If $f''(x_0)$ exists then $\lim_{x \to x_0} \frac{f(x_0+h)-2f(x_0)+f(x_0-h)}{h^2} = f''(x_0)$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, taylor-expansion

> Prove: if $f''(x_0)$ exists then $\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow x_0} \dfrac{f(x_0+h)-2f(x_0)+f(x_0-h)}{h^2} = f''(x_0)$.

I'm not exactly sure how Taylor's theorem fits into all this, but I found the first derivative, and I haven't been able to progress past that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have 
$$
f(x_0+h)=f(x_0)+f'(x_0)h+\frac{1}{2}f''(x_0)h^2+o(h^2),
$$
$$
f(x_0-h)=f(x_0)-f'(x_0)h+\frac{1}{2}f''(x_0)h^2+o(h^2)
$$
Adding together we get
$$
\frac{f(x_0+h)+f(x_0-h)-2f(x_0)}{h^2}=f''(x_0) + \frac{o(h^2)}{h^2}
$$

Comment: Thank you so much!  What is the $o(h^2)$?

Comment: $o(h^2)$ is some function such that $\frac{o(h^2)}{h^2}\rightarrow0$.

Comment: In this case, what you label $O(h^2)$ is $\frac{h^3}{3!}f'''(x) + \cdots$. It should be $O(h^3)$.

Comment: @verger6 how do you sure that $f'''$ exists?

Comment: @user121270 That's a reasonable question. It may not. I guess I don't see why that means the remaining term should be $O(h^2)$.

Comment: @user121270 Oh, my bad. I see now you were using little-o notation. Silly me!

Comment: That is OK. $~~~~$